# Sum of infinite series of the form $\frac{1}{a^n(n-b)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just a basic how-to question. I'm given the series $$\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{4^n(n+2)}$$
How do I go about solving this. I've tried to do a term by term integration to solve and not gotten very far.

Thanks, :)

Comment: When you say solve, do you mean "determine whether the series converges"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1}=\dfrac{x}{1-x}$$
in $|x|<1$, then by integration we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}=-x-\ln(1-x)-\dfrac{x^2}{2}$$
and finally let $x=\dfrac14$ to obtain the result.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{4^n(n+2)}=16\left(-\dfrac14-\ln\dfrac34-\dfrac{1}{32}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+2}=x^{-2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}-x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$
and we know the MacLaurin series for log
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}=-\log(1-x)\quad\lvert x\rvert<1.
$$
Substitute $x=\frac14$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4^n(n+2)}=16\left[-\log\left(1-\frac14\right)-\frac14-\frac1{32}\right]
$$